# Python nearest value digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, rounding

I would like to round values to the nearest 10 (0-4 = 0; 5-14 = 1; 15-24=2, etc.)
I can get round to nearest 10, but I want to single digits for each range of numbers, as the example shows.

From -5 to 4 = 0, 5 to 14 = 1, 15 to 24 = 2 etc...

What I have tried...

```
int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10
```

This gives to nearest 10, but starts from 0 and gives to nearest 10 instead of single digit.

Any advice is helpful.

Comment: 95 - 104, what should the rusult be? Single digit again?

Comment: no, that can be double digits.

Comment: This can help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

Comment: `(x + 5) // 10` ? This assumes x is an integer.

Comment: And by the way, please remove the `nearest neighbours` tag, which is totally an unrelated thing!

Comment: @crazyGamer thanks, ill have a look.

Comment: @TomDalton I have tried that, but it doesn't give single digit.

Comment: I does for me on python 2.7 and 3.5, so I'm curious exactly what you're getting?

Comment: My bad, I did it with my previous code I had, `math.ceil`, this ended up giving me more than I expected. I got to work now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply use:

```
int(round(float(x)/10))
```

From the [`documentation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round):

> **`round(number[, ndigits])`**
>
> Return the floating point value number rounded to ndigits digits after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted, it defaults to zero. The result is a floating point number. Values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits; if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done away from 0 (so, for example, round(0.5) is 1.0 and round(-0.5) is -1.0).

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work like this `int(round(x, -1 ) / 10)`